# Comparison of Strong OPerator and Weak * Topologies on B(H)

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras

It is known that in $\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{H})$, the weak operator topology (WOT) is contained in both the strong operator topology (SOT) and $\sigma$-weak topology. In general the SOT and the $\sigma$-weak topology cannot be compared. To prove this we must show that each contains some set that the other does not. Does it suffice to show that there exist functions that are continuous with respect to one topology but not the other?

Comment: It is easier to find a sequence which is convergence in SOT but is not convergence in $\sigma$-weak operator topology, and vice versa.

Comment: I would be grateful for some pointers in that direction. Would, for example, the sequence $\{S_{R}^n\}$, where ${S_{R}}$ is the right shift operator, be an example of a sequence that is $\sigma$ -weak convergent but not SOT convergent? What about the converse?

Comment: Yes, your example of the sequence of powers of the right shift shows that SOT is not coarser than the $\sigma$-weak topology.  The converse is trickier to show directly because the $\sigma$-weak and WOT topologies coincide on norm-bounded sets. The continuous linear functional are the same for WOT and SOT, so it is enough to show that there exists a linear functional that is $\sigma$-weakly continuous but not weakly continuous.

Answer (score 0):

One  may check that: No  sub-basic open set in the strong operator topology is an open set in the weak operator topology.